# How to load two SQL Tables into dataset and how to bind it to ListView?

Tags: asp.net, .net, linq, gridview, dataset

How to bind the tables to the `ListView` and which control should be used
`LinqDataSource` or `ObjectDataSource`,what should be the `DataSourceID` for the `ListView`

My `ListView` Is

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListViewResult" runat="server" DataSourceID="" GroupItemCount="3">
                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <table id="Table1" runat="server" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;">
                            <tr>
                                <td>No data was returned.</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <EmptyItemTemplate>
<td id="Td1" runat="server" />
                    </EmptyItemTemplate>
                    <GroupTemplate>
                        <tr id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server">
                            <td id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </GroupTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <td id="Td2" runat="server" style="">ID:
                            <asp:DynamicControl ID="DynamicControl1" runat="server" DataField="ID" Mode="Insert" ValidationGroup="Insert" />
                            <br />Image:
                            <asp:DynamicControl ID="DynamicControl2" runat="server" DataField="Image" Mode="Insert" ValidationGroup="Insert" />
                            <br />Name:
                            <asp:DynamicControl ID="DynamicControl3" runat="server" DataField="Name" Mode="Insert" ValidationGroup="Insert" />
                            <br />Age:
                            <asp:DynamicControl ID="DynamicControl4" runat="server" DataField="Age" Mode="Insert" ValidationGroup="Insert" />
                            <br />Height:
                            <asp:DynamicControl ID="DynamicControl5" runat="server" DataField="Height" Mode="Insert" ValidationGroup="Insert" />
                            <br />Education:
                            <asp:DynamicControl ID="DynamicControl6" runat="server" DataField="Education" Mode="Insert" ValidationGroup="Insert" />
                            <br />CurrentStatus:
                            <asp:DynamicControl ID="DynamicControl7" runat="server" DataField="CurrentStatus" Mode="Insert" ValidationGroup="Insert" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" ValidationGroup="Insert" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
                            <br /></td>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <td id="Td3" runat="server" style="background-color: #FFFBD6;color: #333333;">ID:
                            <asp:DynamicControl ID="DynamicControl8" runat="server" DataField="ID" Mode="ReadOnly" />
                            <br />Image:
                            <asp:DynamicControl ID="DynamicControl9" runat="server" DataField="Image" Mode="ReadOnly" />
                            <br />Name:
                            <asp:DynamicControl ID="DynamicControl10" runat="server" DataField="Name" Mode="ReadOnly" />
                            <br />Age:
                            <asp:DynamicControl ID="DynamicControl11" runat="server" DataField="Age" Mode="ReadOnly" />
                            <br />Height:
                            <asp:DynamicControl ID="DynamicControl12" runat="server" DataField="Height" Mode="ReadOnly" />
                            <br />Education:
                            <asp:DynamicControl ID="DynamicControl13" runat="server" DataField="Education" Mode="ReadOnly" />
                            <br />CurrentStatus:
                            <asp:DynamicControl ID="DynamicControl14" runat="server" DataField="CurrentStatus" Mode="ReadOnly" />
                            <br /></td>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <LayoutTemplate>
                        <table id="Table2" runat="server">
                            <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                                <td id="Td4" runat="server">
                                    <table id="groupPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="1" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                                        <tr id="groupPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="Tr2" runat="server">
                                <td id="Td5" runat="server" style="text-align: center;background-color: #FFCC66;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: #333333;">
                                    <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PageSize="9">
                                        <Fields>
                                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowLastPageButton="True" />
                                        </Fields>
                                    </asp:DataPager>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </LayoutTemplate>
                    <SelectedItemTemplate>
                        <td id="Td6" runat="server" style="background-color: #FFCC66;font-weight: bold;color: #000080;">ID:
                            <asp:DynamicControl ID="DynamicControl15" runat="server" DataField="ID" Mode="ReadOnly" />
                            <br />Image:
                            <asp:DynamicControl ID="DynamicControl16" runat="server" DataField="Image" Mode="ReadOnly" />
                            <br />Name:
                            <asp:DynamicControl ID="DynamicControl17" runat="server" DataField="Name" Mode="ReadOnly" />
                            <br />Age:
                            <asp:DynamicControl ID="DynamicControl18" runat="server" DataField="Age" Mode="ReadOnly" />
                            <br />Height:
                            <asp:DynamicControl ID="DynamicControl19" runat="server" DataField="Height" Mode="ReadOnly" />
                            <br />Education:
                            <asp:DynamicControl ID="DynamicControl20" runat="server" DataField="Education" Mode="ReadOnly" />
                            <br />CurrentStatus:
                            <asp:DynamicControl ID="DynamicControl21" runat="server" DataField="CurrentStatus" Mode="ReadOnly" />
                            <br /></td>
                    </SelectedItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
```

**My Code is**

```
protected void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (WebTechManiaDataContext Data = new WebTechManiaDataContext())
        {
            string Education = DropDownListEducation.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
            string MaritalStatus = DropDownListMaritalStatus.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
            int From = int.Parse(DropDownListFrom.SelectedItem.Text);
            int To = int.Parse(DropDownListTo.SelectedItem.Text);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            if (RadioButtonGroom.Checked == true | RadioButtonBride.Checked == false)
            {
                if ((From == 21) && (To == 22))
                {
                    var FoundGroom = Data.Males.Where(Males => (Males.Age == 21 || Males.Age == 22) && (Males.Education == Education || Education.Length == 0) && (Males.CurrentStatus == MaritalStatus || MaritalStatus.Length == 0));
                    if (!FoundGroom.Any())
                    {
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('Search result Negetive');</script>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmd = Data.GetCommand(FoundGroom) as SqlCommand;
                        SqlDataAdapter DataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        DataAdapter.Fill(ds);

                        ListViewResult.DataSource = ds;
                        ListViewResult.DataBind();
                    }
                }
                else if ((From == 21) && (To == 23))
                {
                    var FoundGroom = Data.Males.Where(Males => (Males.Age == 21 || Males.Age == 22 || Males.Age == 23) && (Males.Education == Education || Education.Length == 0) && (Males.CurrentStatus == MaritalStatus || MaritalStatus.Length == 0));
                    if (!FoundGroom.Any())
                    {
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('Search result Negetive');</script>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmd = Data.GetCommand(FoundGroom) as SqlCommand;
                        SqlDataAdapter DataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        DataAdapter.Fill(ds);

                        ListViewResult.DataSource = ds;
                        ListViewResult.DataBind();
                    }
                }

                else if ((From == 21) && (To == 24))
                {
                    var FoundGroom = Data.Males.Where(Males => (Males.Age == 21 || Males.Age == 22 || Males.Age == 23 || Males.Age == 24) && (Males.Education == Education || Education.Length == 0) && (Males.CurrentStatus == MaritalStatus || MaritalStatus.Length == 0));
                    if (!FoundGroom.Any())
                    {
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('Search result Negetive');</script>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmd = Data.GetCommand(FoundGroom) as SqlCommand;
                        SqlDataAdapter DataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        DataAdapter.Fill(ds);

                        ListViewResult.DataSource = ds;
                        ListViewResult.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (RadioButtonBride.Checked == true | RadioButtonBride.Checked == false)
            {
                if ((From == 21) && (To == 22))
                {
                    var FoundBride = Data.Females.Where(Females => (Females.Age == 21 || Females.Age == 22) && (Females.Education == Education || Education.Length == 0) && (Females.CurrentStatus == MaritalStatus || MaritalStatus.Length == 0));
                    if (!FoundBride.Any())
                    {
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('Search result Negetive');</script>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmd = Data.GetCommand(FoundBride) as SqlCommand;
                        SqlDataAdapter DataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        DataAdapter.Fill(ds);

                        ListViewResult.DataSource = ds;
                        ListViewResult.DataBind();
                    }
                }
                else if ((From == 21) && (To == 23))
                {
                    var FoundBride = Data.Females.Where(Females => (Females.Age == 21 || Females.Age == 22 || Females.Age == 23) && (Females.Education == Education || Education.Length == 0) && (Females.CurrentStatus == MaritalStatus || MaritalStatus.Length == 0));
                    if (!FoundBride.Any())
                    {
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('Search result Negetive');</script>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmd = Data.GetCommand(FoundBride) as SqlCommand;
                        SqlDataAdapter DataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        DataAdapter.Fill(ds);

                        ListViewResult.DataSource = ds;
                        ListViewResult.DataBind();
                    }
                }

                else if ((From == 21) && (To == 24))
                {
                    var FoundBride = Data.Females.Where(Females => (Females.Age == 21 || Females.Age == 22 || Females.Age == 23 || Females.Age == 24) && (Females.Education == Education || Education.Length == 0) && (Females.CurrentStatus == MaritalStatus || MaritalStatus.Length == 0));
                    if (!FoundBride.Any())
                    {
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('Search result Negetive');</script>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmd = Data.GetCommand(FoundBride) as SqlCommand;
                        SqlDataAdapter DataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        DataAdapter.Fill(ds);

                        ListViewResult.DataSource = ds;
                        ListViewResult.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you're doing all the work in the code-behind to build the data source, and you're setting the ListViewResult.DataSource to the created datasource.  Then you are DataBind()ing, which means you don't need to set a DataSourceID in the ASPX markup.

Comment: Why so many If?, you could just use `Males.Age >= From && Males.Age <= To`

Comment: Garrison Neely - It gives error something like metatable etc etc when i run it.

Comment: Logar314159 - iam a beginner in c# :p

Comment: Garrison Neely - Error is "Could not determine a MetaTable. A MetaTable could not be determined for the data source '' and one could not be inferred from the request URL. Make sure that the table is mapped to the data source, or that the data source is configured with a valid context type and table name, or that the request is part of a registered DynamicDataRoute."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i did this i want to show data of two tables on the ListView, so that i don't need to use two list views on a page,

what i did is,i inserted two ListViews and two LinqDataSource's and attached them  and after that did this.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {

            ListViewGroom.Visible = false;
            ListViewBride.Visible = false;
        }
        else if(Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (RadioButtonGroom.Checked == true)
            {
                ListViewBride.Visible = false;
            }
            else if(RadioButtonBride.Checked == true)
            {
                ListViewGroom.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }



    protected void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (WebTechManiaDataContext Data = new WebTechManiaDataContext())
        {
            string Education = DropDownListEducation.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
            string MaritalStatus = DropDownListMaritalStatus.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
            int From = int.Parse(DropDownListFrom.SelectedItem.Text);
            int To = int.Parse(DropDownListTo.SelectedItem.Text);

            if (RadioButtonGroom.Checked == true | RadioButtonBride.Checked == false)
            {
                if ((From == 21) && (To == 22))
                {
                    var FoundGroom = Data.Males.Where(Males => (Males.Age == 21 || Males.Age == 22) && (Males.Education == Education || Education.Length == 0) && (Males.CurrentStatus == MaritalStatus || MaritalStatus.Length == 0));
                    if (!FoundGroom.Any())
                    {
                        ListViewGroom.Visible = false;
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('Search result Negetive');</script>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ListViewGroom.Visible = true;
                        ListViewGroom.DataSourceID = "";
                        ListViewGroom.DataSource = FoundGroom;
                        ListViewGroom.DataBind();
                    }
                }
                else if ((From == 21) && (To == 23))
                {
                    var FoundGroom = Data.Males.Where(Males => (Males.Age == 21 || Males.Age == 22 || Males.Age == 23) && (Males.Education == Education || Education.Length == 0) && (Males.CurrentStatus == MaritalStatus || MaritalStatus.Length == 0));
                    if (!FoundGroom.Any())
                    {
                        ListViewGroom.Visible = false;
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('Search result Negetive');</script>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ListViewGroom.Visible = true;
                        ListViewGroom.DataSourceID = "";
                        ListViewGroom.DataSource = FoundGroom;
                        ListViewGroom.DataBind();
                    }
                }

                else if ((From == 21) && (To == 24))
                {
                    var FoundGroom = Data.Males.Where(Males => (Males.Age == 21 || Males.Age == 22 || Males.Age == 23 || Males.Age == 24) && (Males.Education == Education || Education.Length == 0) && (Males.CurrentStatus == MaritalStatus || MaritalStatus.Length == 0));
                    if (!FoundGroom.Any())
                    {
                        ListViewGroom.Visible = false;
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('Search result Negetive');</script>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ListViewGroom.Visible = true;
                        ListViewGroom.DataSourceID = "";
                        ListViewGroom.DataSource = FoundGroom;
                        ListViewGroom.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (RadioButtonBride.Checked == true | RadioButtonBride.Checked == false)
            {
                if ((From == 21) && (To == 22))
                {
                    var FoundBride = Data.Females.Where(Females => (Females.Age == 21 || Females.Age == 22) && (Females.Education == Education || Education.Length == 0) && (Females.CurrentStatus == MaritalStatus || MaritalStatus.Length == 0));
                    if (!FoundBride.Any())
                    {
                        ListViewBride.Visible = false;
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('Search result Negetive');</script>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ListViewBride.Visible = true;
                        ListViewBride.DataSourceID = "";
                        ListViewBride.DataSource = FoundBride;
                        ListViewBride.DataBind();
                    }
                }
                else if ((From == 21) && (To == 23))
                {
                    var FoundBride = Data.Females.Where(Females => (Females.Age == 21 || Females.Age == 22 || Females.Age == 23) && (Females.Education == Education || Education.Length == 0) && (Females.CurrentStatus == MaritalStatus || MaritalStatus.Length == 0));
                    if (!FoundBride.Any())
                    {
                        ListViewBride.Visible = false;
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('Search result Negetive');</script>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ListViewBride.Visible = true;
                        ListViewBride.DataSourceID = "";
                        ListViewBride.DataSource = FoundBride;
                        ListViewBride.DataBind();
                    }
                }

                else if ((From == 21) && (To == 24))
                {
                    var FoundBride = Data.Females.Where(Females => (Females.Age == 21 || Females.Age == 22 || Females.Age == 23 || Females.Age == 24) && (Females.Education == Education || Education.Length == 0) && (Females.CurrentStatus == MaritalStatus || MaritalStatus.Length == 0));
                    if (!FoundBride.Any())
                    {
                        ListViewBride.Visible = false;
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('Search result Negetive');</script>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ListViewBride.Visible = true;
                        ListViewBride.DataSourceID = "";
                        ListViewBride.DataSource = FoundBride;
                        ListViewBride.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

hided the ListView's according to requirement.

Answer (score 1):

i think it could be:

```
ListViewResult.DataSource = ds;
```

use

```
ListViewResult.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

or

```
ListViewResult.DataSource = ds.Tables("TableName");
```

and please replace all of these:

```
if(From = 21 && To = 24)
{
    (Males.Age == 21 || Males.Age == 22 || Males.Age == 23 || Males.Age == 24)
}
```

just with

```
(Males.Age >= From && Males.Age <= To)
```

Comment: It says System.Data.DataSet does not contain a defination for 'Table' .